# May I create a dataframe from a set in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

```
relations = []
... 
rel_dict = {'start': start, 'end': end, 'type': relationship}
if rel_dict not in relations:
    relations.append(rel_dict)


rel_df = pd.DataFrame(relations)
```

This is the code I am creating a dataframe, and the following slows down a lot:

```
if rel_dict not in relations
```

If I define 'relations' as a set, can DataFrame take a set to create a dataframe? If I also want to keep the order in the set, can I do it?

Or maybe I should define 'relations' as a dict:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
relations = OrderedDict()
... 
if rel_dict not in relations:
    relations[rel_dict] =  rel_dict
```

What's your suggestion?

Comment: The type of `rel_dict` is `dict` right? Then both OrderedDict and set will not work out of the box, as `dict` is not hashable.

Comment: Yes， it's a regular dict.

Comment: @psarka what about if I do relations[hash(rel_dict)] = rel_dict?

Comment: It will tell you that `rel_dict` is unhashable :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ideas:

**First**, use `frozendict`, which is like a python dict but hashable (and immutable). Pandas dataframe constructor does not mind taking set of frozen dicts, so this will work:

```py
relations = set()
...
rel_dict = frozendict(start=start, end=end, type=relationship)
relations.add(rel_dict)

rel_df = pd.DataFrame(relations)
```

This will loose the ordering, so to keep it we can replace the `set` by `dict` (you are using python 3.6 or later, right?)

```py
relations = dict()
...
rel_dict = frozendict(start=start, end=end, type=relationship)
relations[rel_dict] = None

rel_df = pd.DataFrame(relations.keys())
```

**Second**, feed the whole thing to pandas and deduplicate after

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(rel_dicts).drop_duplicates(keep='first')
```

Not sure which one is faster, you will have to try.

Comment: For frozendict, is there a way to keep the insert order?

Comment: using dict migh be the best bet, let me update the answer.

Comment: Just found that drop_duplicates() is already used in later lines of code, so I would choose the second approach. If the dict wouldn't be huge, probably it's better.

Comment: BTW, in the first approach, where do rel_dicts come from? Currently 'relations' is a list and regular dict won't work as you said.

Comment: You did not show where the rel_dicts come from in your sample, so I assumed that they are in some kind of list or iterable which I called `rel_dicts`. There are no issues storing dicts in lists.

Comment: There is no rel_dicts. There is only 'relations', which is a list of dict. But I see how to do approach 1: replace a list of dict with a frozendict of dict.

Comment: No, replace a list of dict with a dict of frozendict :) ~~I'll update the answer.~~ No, actually, could you update the question first, to indicate where the `rel_dict`s come from? Because as it is now, there are `relations` which is an empty list from the start, and `rel_dict`s materialize from nowhere to be added to it.

Comment: I added one line: rel_dict = {...}. That's where rel_dict is formed and then if it doesn't exist in the relations list, append it.

Comment: Et voila! I updated the answer as well :)